# Возможно ли в markdown отобразить произвольне html-код и стили?

Tags: bootstrap, документация, markdown

Собирался задокументировать некоторые HTML/CSS/JavaScript виджеты (предположим, что просто улучшенные поля ввода или радиокнопки), но тут же задался вопросом: как отобразить в markdown-документации не только исходный код для копи-пасты, но и результат его выполнения?

Рассмотрим на примере документации Bootstrap 4. Допустим, мы хотим в markdown задокументировать компонент Alert. Исходный код в в markdown оформляется примерно так (может, ошибся в указании языка):

````
```HTML
<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
  A simple secondary alert—check it out!
</div>
```
````

Теперь хотелось видеть в md-файле не только исходный код, но и как будет выглядеть этот самый alert в браузере. Как этого добиться? (Помимо рендеринга HTML-кода нужно ещё как-то решить вопрос со стилями).

Если Вы знаете какие-то средства, альтернативные Markdown, то порекомендуйте. Главное, чтобы этот файл с документацией можно было хранить в папке с html, css и js-реализацией, и просматривать в оффлайне.

[image]

Comment: Не стоит превращать не предназначенное для этого в кашу из текста и HTML :) сделайте лучше ссылку на HTML пример. Хотя любой HTML код можно вставлять в Markdown, но это портит документацию, как минимум, например при её автоматической обработке..

Comment: Что используете для отображения маркдауна и где? То, что вы хотите, легко реализовать с помощью `kramdown` (библиотека для ruby для генерации html из маркдауна)

Comment: Хотя нет, я не совсем правильно сначала понял. Применить кастомные стили и т.д. и т.п. к готовым элементам вы сможете, встроить html в страницу с маркдауном — нет, только вручную.

Comment: @NewView, и всё бы замечательно, но что если таких примеров - несколько сотен? (В документации Bootstrap, например, сколько примеров?). Также ссылка на пример не устраивает меня потому, что она требует подключения к интернету и её придётся открывать в браузере, а мне нужно в среде разработки.

Comment: @Peter Samokhin, md просматриваю в интегрированной среде разработки (PhpStorm и NetBeans). Kramdown? Всё бы замечательно, но поддерживает ли её IDE...

Comment: @БоковГлеб да скорее всего нет, а зачем? Тот же мардаун, только с плюшами. Правда все плюшки появляются только после генерации HTML, а вам как я понял всё в маркдауне оставить надо? Вы с помощью чего документацию пишете, куда-то зальёте  или для себя локально?

Comment: @Peter Samokhin, пишу с помощью среды разработки (WebStorm). В ближайшее время никуда заливать не планируется; документацию каждого компонента планируется хранить в папке с его реализацией (что рекомендовано методологией БЭМ).

Comment: Вставляйте картинки элемента :) куда уж проще, и портабельно, и видно.. (скриншоты)