# Какие средства подходят для документирования HTML/CSS/JS с запускаемыми примерами?

Tags: html, css, документация, markdown

В вопросе [Возможно ли в markdown отобразить произвольне html-код и стили?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846757/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-markdown-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5-html-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8) я узнал, что в markdown нельзя вставлять сниппеты с кодом (то есть не только исходный код, например HTML+CSS, но и результат его рендеринга). Хорошо, а что тогда лучше походит для документирования кода с примерами (исходный код + результат его выполнения)?

- Картинки не подходят в качестве альтернативы отрендеренному HTML&CSS: организация картинок, их обновление и так далее отнимут много времени. Плюс к этому, невозможна анимация (например, при наведении мышью), кликабельность и так далее.
- Допускается вставка сниппетов JSFiddle или CodePen.
- Wiki сайта Bitbucket вставку произвольного HTML-кода, в частности сниппетов JSFiddle/CodePen не поддерживает.
- Даже сервис [sites.google](https://sites.google.com/), и тот оказался бесполезен. Пытаюсь вставить HTML-код на новом сайте, а он тупо не рендерится без всяких предупреждений об ошибках. После получасовых попыток узнаю на [форуме](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/AQGVK-a9UB4):

> You cannot edit the HTML on New Sites.  HTML editing on classic sites
>   is limited.

Причём под "cannot" подразумевается не заблокированная кнопка "добавить HTML", а, как я уже сказал выше, тупо не рендерящийся HTML без всяких предупреждений.

Comment: А почему бы не посмотреть в сторону `GitHub Pages`? Вы можете собрать там маленький сайт со всеми необходимыми стилями и скриптами

Answer (score 1):

Желательно выбирать под стек технологий.
Есть, например, [docsify](https://docsify.js.org/) для Vue.js и [DocSPA](https://swimlane.github.io/DocSPA/) для Angular.